# How do you return an Array rather than an Object

Tags: php, arrays, function, mysqli

I have implemented this and it returns an array as expected WITHIN the function, like so:

```
public function get_events()
    {


        $query = "SELECT * FROM events;";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->Database, $query))
        {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $resultObject = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }

        $myArray = array();
        $size = mysqli_num_rows($resultObject);
        for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
        {
            $myArray[$i] = mysqli_fetch_array($resultObject, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        }

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($myArray);

   }

/* CALL */
$Events = new Events();
$Events->get_events();
```

An array displays as i would expect.

However, when i set it to 'return $myArray' rather than 'print_r' and call the function again it returns:

```
/* CALL */
$Events = new Events();
$Events->get_events(); 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($Events);
```

This is returned -->

```
   Events Object
    (
    [Database] => mysqli Object
        (
            [affected_rows] => -1
            [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: f373ea5dd5538761406a8022a4b8a374418b240e $
            [client_version] => 50011
            [connect_errno] => 0
            [connect_error] => 
            [errno] => 0
            [error] => 
            [error_list] => Array
                (
                )

            [field_count] => 10
            [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP
            [info] => 
            [insert_id] => 0
            [server_info] => 5.6.21
            [server_version] => 50621
            [stat] => Uptime: 100448  Threads: 1  Questions: 1057  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 124  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 83  Queries per second avg: 0.010
            [sqlstate] => 00000
            [protocol_version] => 10
            [thread_id] => 186
            [warning_count] => 0
        )
```

I would like to be able to return an array so that I can use the query in multiple instances. Rather than echoing the html out within the function and having to repeat the same query elsewhere for the same data.

Comment: you are printing the object $event, if you want you can print_r($Events->get_events()) or just put it in a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/* CALL */
$Events = new Events();
$myArray = $Events->get_events(); 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($myArray);
```

You have to assign your output to a variable.